# PHPMailer->send, extended result

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

PHPMailer->Send reports true or false depending whether or not it was able to send a message.  Would it be possible to alter the code so it reports not just true but some extended status information regarding the headers returned by the other server.  I have noticed, when using services such as SendGrid that the other mail server appends information beyond a simple 250 response.  I am now using Zoho's SMTP server since I have run into issues with mail via SendGrid being rejected because of missing DKM/SPF records.  Sigh... !  I know, cheapskate me - I am using their free service.  I might well go one rung up the ladder but they do not give the option of setting up SPF records etc unless you subscribe to the "Silver" service at the customary penny short of the USD 80 per month figure - which is out of my reach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find additional information in the `ErrorInfo` property, but it won't give you the detail you need. There is [an open pull request](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/pull/311) to add this to PHPMailer for exactly the reasons you give, but I've not yet accepted it - however, you could adapt it to use yourself without PHPMailer needing to support it yet.